# Setting up a second Angular application on same server using NGINX

Tags: nginx, node.js

I currently have a AngularJS application running on my virtual private server. To run this I'm using NGINX, Node and 'http-server' and pm2 to keep everything running.

So I start my backend using for example 'node server.js' (port 3000) and I setup a second process of 'http-server' (which I think runs on port 8080) in the public folder.

This is the configuration of my NGINX:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mywebsite.be;

location /{
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
}
}
```

Now I would like to setup a second application which is made with Angular (2). I'm trying to also run my backend with node on port 3001 and then starting http-server on port 8081.

How should I configure my NGINX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a second location with the correct proxy_pass directive (based on your configuration):

```
location /otherlocation {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
}
```

You can match on *location* or if you wish, on a second diffrent domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like it's kind of working, though when I try an API call it looks like somehow NGINX adds a /.

So my  call only works when I call for example /otherlocationapi while it should work when I call /otherlocation/api . Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: It looks like I had to add a / to the end of the path!

Answer (score 0):

Federico's answer helped me further but I also wanted to post my final solution.

I setup two locations right now, one for the backend (api) and one for the gui.

```
location /backend/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
}
location /gui/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:4200/;
}
```

This works for me for now! :)

Comment: Hi! Glad it works with your setup. not sure why you need to add an extra / , I will investigate...